# Power Transmitted along the string by a sine wave

Tags: energy, waves, power

I have referred several sources which derived the equation for the power transmitted along a string by a sine wave.

However,  I could not find anywhere **what exactly is it?**

"Along a string" makes me think that energy is transmitted  from one part of the string to the other,  but I find myself unable to form a well defined image of the same in my head.

Could anyone explain the same with some graphics( pictures or animation)  in a clear way as to what this exactly is?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Send a single pulse on a string with a ring attached on the other side. The ring will move up when the pulse strikes it, thereby transferring KE to it

Comment: Energy is an abstract thing; you can't really show it in pictures. I assume you know how kinetic and potential energies are defined. In that case my answer below should help. Textbooks will give graphs of these quantities for a portion of string as the wave passes through, but your question suggests that these aren't what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since any part of the string oscillates as the wave passes through, it's clear that (except twice per cycle) it has kinetic energy. And it's also clear that kinetic energy is *passing through* – imagine that the wave source has just been switched on, and successive parts of the string start to oscillate as the wave advances.

What's not quite so obvious is that elastic potential energy is also being transported by the wave. In a transverse wave the string is slightly lengthened by parts of the wave profile and so has varying elastic energy as the wave passes through. It turns out that for a given small portion of string, the elastic energy varies in phase with the kinetic energy, unlike the antiphase relationship for a single mass oscillating on a spring. You might care to read the answers to "[Energy density in a string wave](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/476415/195949)", asked on 22nd January 2018 on this site.

Comment: @ Claudio Saspinski  Thank you for putting in the link. How does one put in a link?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://commonmark.org/help/). CommonMark is the Mark-down editor server/client standard used by StackExchange. I put the word 'this' in brackets, followed by the URL in parentheses: https://commonmark.org/help/