# How is work equal to $Tds$ for an element of string in a transverse wave?

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves, work, potential-energy, string

[image]

Assume that an infinitesimal element of a string is horizontal, and due to a wave passing on it, it's shape changes and is inclined as shown in the figure.
Assuming constant tension $T$ it's claimed that the work done on the element is $Tds$ where $ds$ is the elongation of the element from its horizontal position.

I cannot understand how the work is $Tds$. When we calculate work done on a particle we take the dot product of the displacement vector and the force. In this case it appears that the displacement is in the vertical direction but that's incorrect. As is shown in the next picture.

Can anyone please show how the work is $Tds$ in this case.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking why the potential energy in a bit of string is given by $T$ times the change in length of the bit of string string, or are you asking about the work that one bit of string does on the next bit as a  wave propagaties down the string? The relevent displacement is quite different in the two cases. In the second case the rate of working  is $-Ty' \dot y$ where $y'$ is your $\Delta A/\Delta x$

Comment: Yes why the potential is given by T times the elongation. I'd be grateful if you  clarify :)

Comment: According to AP French" the potential energy can be calculated by finding the amount by which the string when deformed it is longer than when it is straight. This extension multipled  by the assumed constant tension T ,is the work done in the deformation".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, That is correct. It is indeed assumed that the stretch is not sufficient to change the tension.  The relevent displacement is always the bit causing the stretch, not the sideways displacment that you call $\Delta A$ as that is perpendicular to the string, and hence perpendicular to the tension force, for small displacements. I'll call the transverse displacement $dy$, as that's what most book have. The stretch is then
$$
\delta s= \sqrt{(d x)^2+(d y)^2}- dx= \left\{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}- 1\right\}dx\\
\approx \frac 12 \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 dx
$$

Comment: Thanks,so  $\delta s$  is the extra stretch  i get that, but how is work Tds then?

Comment: If you move something through a distance $ds$ against tension $T$ the work is $Tds$. As I said, the other movement in displacing the string is always at right angles to the string, and hence the tension, and so does no work.

Comment: I've added another picture, the only displacement is vertical, then the work should be 0?

Comment: As the line segment tilts up there is a component of the force parallel to the tension as you can see in your drawing. The vertical line is -- not perpendicular to the hypotenuse. Obviously the work work done to get there is $T$ times the change in length of the hypotenuse.

Comment: To make the string change its orientation, $T$ should have a component perpendicular to the string. So to be precise the work should be $T_l.ds$ where$T_l$ is the component of tension along the string. Is then the equation of work an approximation that becomes an equality for a massless string which doesn't need any force to change its orientation?