# Why doesn't a compression pulse on a spring move backwards?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, waves, acoustics, spring

[image]I've a  spring and I give it a single impulse towards left. A compression zone is produced as is shown in the picture, then this compression moves ahead to the left of the spring and we see a compression zone in the middle of the spring .

My question is that why doesn't this compression in the middle of the string move both to the left and right as it relaxes (as I've drawn on the picture)? I have seen that the correct thing is that the compression pulse will move towards the left only,  however we can argue that the compression in the middle of the spring will push on both sides of the spring and hence produce pulses going both towards left and right.

Could anyone please help me in understanding as to why the compression pulse will go only to the left and not to the right.

Also are there going to be any rarefactions produced in the spring if I just push it and leave it there?

Comment: Hint: read up on group velocity of waves.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. I did study it but I'm afraid I couldn't find it relevant. Could you explain it a little?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third example in your image is a snapshot of the pulse.  Unfortunately the snapshot can only show us the deformation (or potential energy) in the spring.  It cannot show us the velocity of the elements in the spring.

If the compression is created, held statically in place, and then released, the waves will move in both directions as you show in the final example.

But when created from a compression from the right, the elements of the spring will also have a velocity.  This velocity when combined with the potential energy of the compression serve to cancel out the pulse to the right and only allow the pulse to the left to propagate.

Comment: So , in the third example the compression pulse has some velocity to the left and the force that this compression applies onto it neutralises the wave trying to go out to the right?

Comment: Since i posted this question I've seen many videos, which show a rarefaction as well as compression, will any rarefaction be produced in this case?

Comment: @BowlOfRed  Very interesting--Are there any web links (or text books) for this 'velocity explanation' ?

Comment: @user45664, i believe you like wave physics, I'd be glad if you could help me here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/603812/how-is-work-equal-to-tds-for-an-element-of-string-in-a-transverse-wave/603854? noredirect=1#comment1359353_603854            and here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/603864/why-do-we-generally-get-reflected-and-transmitted-waves-that-too-having-same-fre/603970#603970

Comment: See https://www.researchgate.net/publication/340085346